# Is all code run inside an mvc controller method in the same session?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, first-level-cache

I have the following model:

many to many between entity `Foo` and `Bar`. Foo has a LinkedHashSet of `Bar` annotated with `@OrderBy`.

Controller includes a method that first saves a new Bar to the set, and then gets all Bar from one Foo.

```
Set<Bar> methodName(FooId fid, Bar b){
    fooService.addBar(fid, b);
    return fooService.getBarsOfFoo(fid);
}
```

service methods:

```
@Transactional
void addBar(UUID fid, Bar b){
    Foo f = fooRepository.getFoo(fid);
    f.getBars().add(b);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
Set<Bar> getBarsOfFoo(UUID fid){
    return fooRepository.getFoo(fid).getBars();
}
```

the issue is that when calling the method, all Bars are ordered except the last introduced one. I think it has something to do with hibernate first-level caching, but I am not sure when the session associated with that method starts or ends.

Are both session methods from that controller method run within the same session?

Comment: Please show the code of addBar and getBarsOfFoo

Answer (score 1):

A  Hibernate session is not the same as an MVC controller session from the official documentation https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions

it depends on your configuration and who and how you're creating this session

but in principle, there are 3 patterns

**session-per-request**

> the session-per-request implementation pattern. A single Session and a
>   single database transaction implement the processing of a particular
>   request event (for example, a Http request in a web application). Do
>   never use the session-per-operation anti-pattern! (There are extremely
>   rare exceptions when session-per-operation might be appropriate, you
>   will not encounter these if you are just learning Hibernate.)

**session-per-request-with-detached-objects**

> Once persistent objects are considered detached during user think-time
>   and have to be reattached to a new Session after they have been
>   modified.

**session-per-conversation**

> In this case a single Session has a bigger scope than a single
>   database transaction and it might span several database transactions.
>   Each request event is processed in a single database transaction, but
>   flushing of the Session would be delayed until the end of the
>   conversation and the last database transaction, to make the
>   conversation atomic. The Session is held in disconnected state, with
>   no open database connection, during user think-time. Hibernate's
>   automatic optimistic concurrency control (with versioning) is used to
>   provide conversation isolation.

So viewing the documentation you probably using session-per-conversation so might to need to flush your session before your next call.